# No entiendo el problema, es como si usara punteros

Tags: python-3.x

Relaciono varios objetos mediante variables, b es un objeto que sirve para almacenar un objeto a que a su vez almacena un objeto a. El problema radica en que al momento de modificar la lista no, tanto el objeto a y el que esta relacionado tienen los mismos valores, a pesar de que cambie uno solo.

```
import os

class a():
    no = [[0,0],[0,0]]
    anode = None


class b():
    node = a()

b = b()

b.node.anode = a()
b.node.no[0][0] = 1

print(b.node.no)
print(b.node.anode.no)
```

resultado:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: que tal amigo, podrias ser un poco mas claro sobre tu problema, para poder ayudarte; gracias

Comment: *es como si usara punteros*, no son punteros, aunque parece que se comportan como tal. Se trata de una variable *mutable*, y cuando asignas (operador de asignación) está variable a otro nombre, no se crea una copia del objeto, simplemente se crea una referencia al mismo objeto al que apunta la variable original. Por lo tanto, lo que alteres en una será al final alterado en *todas*, ya que realmente es el mismo objeto. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Las variables de clase son tomadas por referencia y compartidas por todas las instancias: cualquier cambio se reproduce en las demás, mientras que las variables inicializadas dentro del bloque `__init__` son de instancia y solo pueden ser usadas desde dicha instancia...

```
class a():
    no = [[0,6],[0,8]]
    anode = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.no = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        self.anode = None


class b():
    node = a()


b = b()

b.node.anode = a()
b.node.no[0][0] = 1


print(b.node.no)
print(b.node.anode.no)
print(a.no)


[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 6], [0, 8]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay unos cuantos problemas en tu código, que no tienen por qué ser problemas si sabes exactamente lo que estás haciendo, pero que pueden causar grandes quebraderos de cabeza si no lo tienes tan claro. Son los siguientes:

1. Defines una clase llamada `b`, pero más adelante haces `b = b()`, con lo que cambias el significado del símbolo `b` que deja ya de ser una clase para pasar a ser una instancia de una clase. Para evitar equivocarse mejor seguir el convenio recomendado por el PEP8 sobre [nombrado](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), en concreto: usar nombres de clase que comiencen por mayúsculas y usen CamelCase y nombres de variables en minúsculas y que usen snake_case. En este caso, podrías llamar `A` y `B` a las clases, y `a` y `b` a las instancias (objetos)
2. En ambas clases estás usando *atributos de clase*. Es decir, tanto `no` como `anode` en la clase `a`  como `node` en la clase `b` son todos ellos atributos de clase. Los atributos de clase se comportan de forma un poco inesperada en Python y lo más probable es que *no querías usar eso*, sino atributos de instancia (objeto).
3. En algunas asignaciones de tu código intentas *sobreescribir* un atributo de clase, pero a través de una instancia. Eso causará que Python cree un atributo de instancia. En otras asignaciones de tu código en cambio usas *indirectamente* un atributo de clase para modificar un valor contenido en una lista, y aquí el comportamiento es diferente (no porque sea una lista, sino porque no estás modificando directamente el atributo, luego lo explico mejor).

Voy a renombrar las clases a mayúsculas para seguir el convenio, pero voy a dejar los atributos de clase tal como los tenías para explicar **qué está pasando con tu código**. Aprovecho para quitar los `()` en las definiciones de clase, que solo son necesarios para poner dentro la clase base en caso de que estés usando herencia (y no la estás usando).

### Declaración de la clases

```
class A:
    no = [[0,0],[0,0]]
    anode = None


class B:
    node = A()
```

De momento esto ha creado dos símbolos: `A` y `B`. Ambos son clases. La clase `A` tiene un par de atributos llamados respectivamente `A.no` y `A.anode`. Esos atributos existen ya como parte del símbolo `A`, aunque no se cree ningún objeto (instancia) de esa clase. El atributo `A.no` es una referencia (si quieres, puntero) a una lista que contiene `[[0,0], [0,0]]`. Esta lista por tanto existe ya en memoria aún antes de que se haya creado ningún objeto de la clase `A`.

La clase `B` tiene un atributo llamado `B.node`. Este existe ya también antes de crear ningún objeto de la clase `B`, y ya está inicializado con el resultado de `A()`, es decir, está inicializado con una **instancia** de la clase `A`.

Gráficamente, al ejecutar el código anterior, Python ha creado ya las siguientes estructuras de datos:

[image: Grafico]

Observa algo importante. **La instancia de la clase A no tiene atributos**. El campo `node` de la clase `B` apunta a una instancia de `A()`, pero esa instancia no tiene ningún atributo porque los atributos los has definido *en la clase* y no en el objeto. Esto es importante, porque si intentas acceder al atributo `no` de esa instancia, Python lo buscará en el objeto, y al no encontrarlo lo buscará en la clase `A`, que será donde lo encuentre.

### Instancia de una clase

Sigamos con tu código:

```
b = B()  # Crear instancia de la clase B
```

Esto simplemente añade lo siguiente al gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, `b` se convierte en una referencia a una instancia de la clase B, pero **esta instancia tampoco tiene atributos**.

### Primera asignación

Ahora viene la parte interesante:

```
b.node.anode = A()
```

El intento de acceder a `b.node` buscará el atributo `node` dentro del objeto señalado por `b`. Ese objeto no tiene ese atributo. Así que Python buscará en la clase a que pertenece ese objeto (`B`) y allí sí que encuentra el atributo `B.node`. usará por tanto ese atributo. Su valor es una instancia de `A` como hemos visto antes.

El intento de usar a continuación `.anode` buscará el atributo `anode` en la instancia de `A` a la que señala `B.node`. De nuevo ocurre que no lo encuentra porque la instancia de A no tiene atributos. Así que lo buscará en su clase, es decir, buscará `A.anode`. Allí sí encuentra un atributo que tiene el valor `None`. Ahora bien, estamos **reasignando** ese atributo.

Cuando intentas reasignar un atributo de clase Python no lo hará. En vez de eso **creará un atributo de objeto** y será ese atributo el que asignará. Es decir, en este punto creará un atributo llamado `anode` *dentro de la instancia de A* a la que apuntaba `B.node`, y asignará a ese atributo el valor que le quieras asignar. En este caso le asignas `A()`, es decir, creas otra instancia de `A` y eso será lo que asignes allí.

Por tanto, tras ejecutar esa línea, éste será el panorama:

[image: Tras asignar]

Observa la cajita naranja. Es el primer atributo de instancia que aparece hasta ahora. Esa instancia particular de la clase `A` tiene un atributo llamado `anode` porque **has intentado reasignar** el atributo de clase. Otras instancias de la clase `A` no tienen por qué tener ese atributo mientras no lo intentes asignar. Así, la instancia que acabamos de crear (en verde en la figura) no tiene ningún atributo de instancia.

### Segunda asignación

Finalmente vamos con:

```
b.node.no[0][0] = 1
```

Se intenta acceder al atributo de instancia `b.node`, pero éste no existe. Se busca entonces ese atributo en la clase, y se encuentra `B.node`, y ese será el utilizado. Según el diagrama ese atributo "apunta" a una instancia de A (la que hemos modificado en la asignación anterior).

Se intenta acceder al atributo `.no`  de esa instancia, pero tal atributo no existe. Se busca entonces en la clase y se encuentra `A.no`, y ese será por tanto el que se usará.

A diferencia de la primera asignación, en este caso **no estamos reasignando el atributo**, ya que no estamos haciendo `b.node.no = otra_cosa`. Si hiciéramos eso, se crearía un atributo de objeto, igual que había ocurrido cuando asignamos `b.node.anode`.

En vez de reasignar ese atributo, usamos el "puntero" que contiene, que señala a la lista, para modificar directamente la lista. Al poner `b.node.no[0]` simplemente "seguimos" al puntero para llegar al elemento apuntado, que es una lista con dos elementos, por lo que `b.node.no[0][0]` irá al primero de esos elementos.

Es decir, gráficamente pinto de rojo el valor que acaba de cambiar:

[image: Tras asignar lista]

Es importante que comprendas que no es lo mismo `b.node.no = 100` por ejemplo, que `b.node.no[0][0] = 100`. En el primer caso estarías intentando reasignar el atributo de clase y en ese caso Python crearía un atributo de objeto, como ocurrió con la primera asignación. En el segundo caso no estás reasignando el atributo de clase, sino el valor al que apunta, por lo que no se crea un atributo de objeto.

### Imprimir resultados

Ahora ya podemos interpretar los resultados, con ayuda de la figura anterior:

```
print(b.node.no)
```

`b.node` no existe. Se usa entonces `B.node`. En la figura vemos que `B.node` apunta a una instancia de `A`, que tiene su propio atributo de instancia llamado `anode`, pero que no estamos usando aquí. En cambio se intenta acceder a su atributo `no`, que no existe, por lo que se usa `A.no`. Ese apunta a la lista que acabamos de modificar, por lo que vemos `[[1,0], [0,0]]`

```
print(b.node.anode.no)
```

De nuevo `b.node` no existe, por lo que se usa `B.node`. En la figura vemos que la instancia a la que `B.node` señala sí que tiene un atributo `anode`, el cual señala a otra instancia (en verde en la figura). Se intenta acceder al atributo `no` de esa instancia verde, el cual no existe. Por tanto se usa `A.no` (el atributo de clase) y ese señala a la lista antes modificada, por lo que vemos de nuevo `[[1,0], [0,0]]`

### En resumen

La mezcla de atributos de clase, instancias sin atributos, atributos que se intentan modificar en la clase (y por tanto crean nuevos atributos de instancia) y atributos que se usan para modificar indirectamente valores, lleva a un **caos** importante y difícil de descifrar.

Ahora cabe preguntarse qué pretendías y qué resultado esperabas exactamente, para proporcionar una implementación que haga lo que buscabas. Probablemente no querías usar atributos de clase sino de objeto. Estos atributos no se "declaran" en la clase, sino que se inicializan en el método `__init__()`, mediante sentencias como `self.no = [[0,0], [0,0]]` y `self.node = None`. Eso causa que al crearse un nuevo objeto y ejecutarse el `__init__()`, se creen esos atributos **en el objeto**, evitando parte del caos.

Comment: Me fue de mucha ayuda la explicación, estoy experimentando, lo que buscaba es algo similar a un árbol binario, pero los objetos se relacionaran en forma de rejilla,  estoy usando pygame, y para mostrar ciertas pantallas, aquí el problema radicaba en que me plantee el reto de que fueran tantas pantallas como se requirieran(como un roguelike con salas infinitas), ya he caído en una solución, pero le di vueltas varios dias a esto, hasta logre identificar ese detalle, Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el problema que intentas describir, pero si tienes más dudas al respecto puedes plantear otra pregunta. Si ésta ya ha quedado resuelta puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te haya servido.